# Using ARKit and LiDAR Outdoor under different lightning conditions

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, lidar, lightning

Please help me out. I am struggeling for weeks now with ARKit and LiDAR to build an outdoor app. In the app I want to place an object, save the scene with the object and reconstruct it later on. Now I am using more (invisable) anchors around the object, so it will be easier to reconstruct the saved experience. In the first place it worked well.

But there is one thing. If I've saved the scene on a clowdy (darker) day, it's impossible to reconstruct it on a sunny day. How is this possible? I was thinking that by using LiDAR it's possible to use it in every environment (dark, light, shadows, etc.). I've seen Andy's great article about light estimation (isLightEstimationEnabled), but I don't need to the give the object extra light. It looks that the environment can not be scanned on the right way. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a simple command like: configurartion.useLiDARonlyAndIgnoreLightning?

Thanks,

Marc

Answer (score 0):

As far as we all know, AI is heavily involved in ARKit. This is also true when using a LiDAR scanner. To be honest, I have no idea how to make a LiDAR reconstruct a 3D mesh the same way, whether it's a sunny day or a cloudy one. Such lighting conditions are different for LiDAR + RGBCam vision, because there may be bright hotspots that make recognizable objects unrecognizable. AI remembers lighting situation. And how can we ignore the fact that our mesh is updated dynamically?

Nevertheless, it seems to me that you can slightly improve this situation by disabling the classifier (use `.mesh` property instead of `.meshWithClassification`).

```
config.sceneReconstruction = .mesh
```

Comment: Thanks again Andy for your reply. I was already using .mesh (I don't need classification). Or do you mean that I need to use: .meshWithClassification, for better results? What is wierd is that when you save a scene in a dark environment you can reconstruct it easilly in the same dark environment. Placing objects in sunny enviroments seems to be a problem. Could be something with shadows or so. I was wondering what is the fun of ARKit/LiDAR outdoor if you can't use it? Geo Anchors are still not working in Europe. Probably the next WWDC will surprise us (ARKit 5.0 :-)).

Comment: I meant you don't need a classification. It's not weird: as I said AI controls scanning data and it does take into account a lighting situation.

Comment: I understand. Sorry for my question about the .mesh. I didn't read that part the right way. I hope that I can find a working solution for my app. I was on the right way.